# Python indention error with if/elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement, indentation

I have three lists in this program. 'library' contains a large amount of text, 'references' contains a list of words that follow each other in references, and 'possibles' looks at every time that each item in 'references' appear together so it can get the following word.

The program gets the length of 'references' so it knows how many items to check in 'library', but the piece of code that checks if references has 2 items in it returns 'unexpected indention', and I can't figure out why. Even if I remove the indention, it returns the error. If it is not indented, there is an error because it disrupts the rest of the code.

Below is the entire function. The entire program works aside from the indention error.

```
def possibles_compile():
    compile = 'yes'
    global temp_possibles
    temp_possibles = []
    while compile != 'no':
        if len(reference) == 1:
            for i in range(library_length):
                try:
                    if library[i] == reference[0]:
                        try:
                            temp_possibles.append(library[i + 1])
                        except IndexError:
                            temp_possibles.append(library[0])
        elif len(reference) == 2:
            for i in range(library_length):
                if library[i] == reference[0]:
                    try:
                        if library[i + 1] == reference[1]:
                            try:
                                temp_possibles.append(library[i + 2])
                            except IndexError:
                                temp_possibles.append(library[0])
                    except IndexError:
                        if library[0] == reference[1]:
                                temp_possibles.append(library[1])
        elif len(reference) == 3:
            for i in range(library_length):
                if library[i] == reference[0]:
                    try:
                        library[i + 1] == reference[1]:
                    except IndexError:
                        if library[0] == reference[1]:
                            if library[1] == reference[2]:
                                    temp_possibles.append(library[2])
                    else:
                        try:
                            if library[i + 2] == reference[2]:
                                try:
                                    temp_possibles.append(library[i + 3])
                                except IndexError:
                                    temp_possibles.append(library[0])
                        except IndexError:
                            if library[0] == reference[2]:
                                temp_possibles.append(library[1])
        elif len(reference) == 4:
            for i in range(library_length):
                if library[i] == reference[0]:
                    try:
                        library [i + 1] == reference[1]:
                    except IndexError:
                        if library[0] == reference[1]:
                            if library[1] == reference[2]:
                                if library[2] == reference[3]:
                                    temp_possibles.append(library[3])
                    else:
                        try:
                            library[i + 2] == reference[2]:
                        except IndexError:
                            if library[0] == reference[2]:
                                if library[1] == reference[3]:
                                    temp_possibles.append(library[2])
                        else:
                            try:
                                if library[i + 3] == reference[3]:
                                    try:
                                        temp_possibles.append(library[i + 4])
                                    except IndexError:
                                        temp_possibles.append(library[0])
                            except IndexError:
                                if library[0] == reference[3]:
                                    temp_possibles.append(library[1])
        compile = 'no'
    return 'done'
```

Comment: In your first `if` block you have a `try` statement without a matching `except` (or `finally`) (that's line 7 of the code in your question).

Comment: And then later on you have some misplaced colons. See e.g. line 31. In general your life would be easier if you used an editor with syntax checking, because it could point these errors out to you.

Comment: I *cannot* believe I didn't catch that. I read through it like 20 times and missed it *thank you so much*

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour]. Glad you figured it out :) In the future you need to make a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

The comments opened my eyes to the fact that I had a `try` with no `except` and lots of misplaced colons. Removing the colons and `try` made it work flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Before the line:

```
if library[i] == reference[0]:
```

You created an exception handler but only put the try clause and every **try** must have an associated **except** to it. So I suggest you change your code to:

```
try:
    if library[i] == reference[0]:
    try:
        temp_possibles.append(library[i + 1])
    except IndexError:
        temp_possibles.append(library[0])
except Exception:
    pass # put the exception code you want to executed when handling this exception here
```

Or, you can remove that try clause if it's unnecessary.

Also, be careful with the following lines:

```
library[i + 1] == reference[1]:
library [i + 1] == reference[1]:
library [i + 1] == reference[1]:
```

You're using a colon on a place you shouldn't (unless you wanted to create a condition or an iterate clause).

Comment: [A bare `except` is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54948548/4518341). Instead catch a specific error, or at least `Exception`.

Comment: @wjandrea You're right, just wanted to illustrate the missing clause so the user would be able to adapt to its' needs.

Comment: Then I would suggest changing it to `except Exception` instead.